# Cannot repro javascript bugs exposed by Selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium, requirejs, fluentautomation

I have a web application that utilizes a lot of javascript code. I've noticed that a lot of times in production the tests written using FluentAutomation with Selenium drivers reproduces some bugs very consistently.

For example:

```
define(['knockout'], function(ko) {
    return $('body');
});
```

This code uses jquery, but doesn't list it as a dependency. Its obviously a bug in the javascript code, however this causes an error "undefined is not a function" consistently when run through Fluent Automation\Selenium. The issue is that it works fine when the page is opened in Chrome manually.

I assume it is just a timing issue, but why does this repro so consistently in the Fluent Automation\Selenium tests and never repros for me when I run the same code directly in Chrome? What is different about how FluentAutomation\Selenium is running Chrome that causes this to only repro in that scenario? How can I get this to repro when running it myself in Chrome?